# Making a reading list and confused about ManyToMany relationship between the models - Django

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I am making an app where a user can save books to a "reading" list. I have created 2 models to connect to the custom User model(AbstractBaseUser) I have made.

I am learning how to do this and have been reading the docs.

For the book Model this is what I have. I have created a ManyToMany key with the user since I want the books to be able to be added by other users to their lists once it has been inputted into the book database.

**Books model.py**

```
class Books(models.Model):
ONESTAR = "BD"
TWOSTAR = "OK"
THREESTAR = "GD"
FOURSTAR = "VG"
FIVESTAR = "EX"
DEFAULT = "NA"
READ  = "RB"
NOT_READ = "NR"
WANT_READ = "WR"

BOOK_REVIEW_CHOICES = (
    (DEFAULT, 'Rate Book'),
    (FIVESTAR, 'Excellent'),
    (FOURSTAR, 'Very Good'),
    (THREESTAR, 'Good'),
    (TWOSTAR,'Okay'),
    (ONESTAR, 'Bad'),
)

READ_BOOKS_CHOICES = (
    (READ,  'Read Book'),
    (NOT_READ, 'Didnt Read Book'),
    (WANT_READ, 'Want To Read')
    )

user = models.ManyToManyField(UsrAccounts, related_name='users')
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
book_rating = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=BOOK_REVIEW_CHOICES, default = DEFAULT)
read_status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=READ_BOOKS_CHOICES, default = READ)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path, null= True, blank=True)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

For the list model I have a foreign key for a ManyToOne relationship between a list and user but a ManyToMany between a list and books.

**my List Model.py**

```
class MyList(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    'accounts.UsrAccounts',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
books = models.ManyToManyField(Books, related_name='books')
```

Did I set this up right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should setup `M2M` field on `UserAccount` model point to `Book` model:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    reading_list = models.ManyToManyField('Book', blank=True)
```

If you want to give reading list a title, you should use another model to hold that, like:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    reading_list = models.ManyToManyField('Book', through='ReadingList')

class ReadingList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('UserAccount')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    # some other fields related to a reading list
```

Django doc about [through keyword on M2M field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

By the way, don't use plural form on model names, django will add plural form when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Thats where I was  little confused. Where the ManyToMany goes in regards to connection. I thought that if the User is the parent the ManyToMany goes on the child.

Comment: It goes either way, but do you think it makes more sense logically to get a reading list from user or from a book?

Comment: Logically from the user. lol  Ok I appreciate your help and am going to look at what you recommended.  They say the first answer is usually right and in my planning I though the "through" option was my first choice.